# Fragment transaction on a single tab of ViewPager in SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am creating `ViewPager` in `SherlockFragmentActivity`.
Structure of my app is like `ViewPager`->having three tabs: tab1, tab2, tab3.
In tab2, I want to display different fragments like fragment1->fragment2->fragment3.
In `ViewPager`, I am having three tabs (`Fragment`s) added using `FragmentStatePageAdapter` as shown below.

```
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            SearchTab searchtab = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            BrowseTab browsetab = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            SavedItemsTab savedTab = new Tab3();
            return Tab3;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now in tab2, I have displayed `ListView` in fragment1. When user clicks an item from `ListView`, I want to display another fragment (fragment2) with other `ListView`. I am doing this by fragment transaction as bellow:

```
Fragment newFragment = new Brxxxx_Fragment();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Main_Cat_ID", Main_Category_ID_Str);
args.putString("Main_Cat_Name", Main_Category_Name_Str);

newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.b_p_layoutid, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

After this step, I am able to display another fragment (fragment2), but my old fragment (fragment1) is still visible below the new fragment.

If I want to remove previous fragment without using `replace()`, how should I get the current fragment to pass in remove method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can remove the other fragment if you don't need to navigate back or set background color to the new fragment . You can check that your layout id 'R.id.b_p_layoutid' is of your 'FrameLayout' and not your 'Fragment' id just in case...

```
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove('YOUR_FRAGMENT').commit();
```

**You can check this answer too:**

Visit [Android replace fragment still displays some of the replaced fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958555/android-replace-fragment-still-displays-some-of-the-replaced-fragment)

Visit [Fragment replaced still visible on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771293/fragment-replaced-still-visible-on-background)